# How do I get the "best" ending?

Tags: home

Some endings are clearly better than others.  For instance, in my ending, I chose to blame Norman for everything, even though that clearly contradicts most of what I saw throughout the game.  Also, the dead bodies at the start, and the reason for waking up in that house to begin with, were never explained.

Is there a "best" ending, where these things are explained?  If so, how do I get it?

Comment: Makes me wonder how many possible endings in the game in the first place. It's just annoying having to start again from the beginning instead of starting from a specific saved file.

Comment: is the game just called home? is that an acronym?

Comment: @Xitcod13: http://store.steampowered.com/app/215670/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from the game developer:

> It’s not choose-your-own-adventure, it’s make-your-own-adventure. It’s
>   not a game where there are 15 endings, you get ending A to Z and
>   that’s the ending you get. It’s more that, between the beginning and
>   the end, stuff happens that will reflect how you perceive a bunch of
>   other things.

Which really means there is no best ending.

Comment: Except, even if the author claims otherwise, there are some elements of the game that are definitely **strongly** hinted as being the "correct" version.  Also, there are items in the game that, if you miss, certain story elements are just never explained.   I mentioned cases of both of these in the question.  So, this answer *(even though it's from the horse's mouth)* cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler:

> You dont remember why you wake up in the house because you have alcoholism the book on shelf that wasn't the "right edition" was clearly the big book maybe Rachel's see might have been in allinon. The list of people is a fourth step inventory you probably mutter murdered every one.